# Should I use JQuery instead of PHP for loading external JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got a webpage that makes several calls to external site APIs. Right now, I do this via PHP, and cache the responses to disk (using cachelite) where I can. Even so, [the page](http://www.controlcommandescape.com/games/) seems to load very slowly, and I'm struggling to find a likely cause (the page speed tab in Chrome is not providing any useful clues).

So I wonder if there might be some benefit to having the client process the API calls via JQuery instead, so that at least the initial page load for the user is faster. Is it worth me doing this, or would I be better off trying to optimise the PHP code further?

Comment: FYI: the PageSpeed tab is for client-side loading analysis, not server performance. You might want to try something like New Relic.

Comment: Actually I had previously tried new relic but found it needlessly mired in monetisation prompts which put me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, if you want to have the result of the JSON indexed by Google, you need to parse it through PHP.

If you want the fastest way and less server load, use Javascript to load the JSON, the JSON will be loaded from an external source and cached by the users browser.

What is the load time of the JSON? Maybe the other server is slow?

Comment: +1 what if external site is down? how long does it take to timeout? your site wont load until it finishes

Comment: If it's JSON it's just not visible, and you could show a message untill the JSON is loaded. I think the default timeout of PHP is 30 seconds, so people need to wait 30 seconds untill it is loaded.

Comment: @Waygood good grief, I'm embarrassed to say I hadn't really considered that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is server side scipting. 
If you are not doing anything on server but just loading the contents from external Site APIs
I think it would be better if you use jQuery or javascript to the job for you.

Comment: +1 Why keep the user waiting. It's better to show some sort of feedback while loading (something you can only do if the page has actually loaded - i.e. using JS/jQuery)

Comment: thank you for showing me the light, well put! (I accepted Niels as it was the first reply)

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about the two answers above and think maybe what I could do is combine both approaches, that is to say, have the json fetched and cached by a server-side php script, but have the user-facing PHP files use jquery to load data from the file.